HoldForm Error for Illustrating Coordinates
I am having trouble illustrating tupoint[c, b, a, d, t] in the right diagram. When using the tax unit slider, the red coordinate should be moving along the graph - illustrating the current tax vs. the revenue-maximizing tax.
I tried various combinations of N[.] and other ways to explicitly define the coordinates of the point.
The error message is: "Coordinate {HoldForm[$CellContext`t$$], 0.25 (1400 - HoldForm[$CellContextt$$]) HoldForm[$CellContextt$$]} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."
dq[c_, b_, p_] := c/b - p/b
dp[c_, b_, q_] := c - b*q
(*Supply and Inverse Supply*)
sq[a_, d_, p_] := -(a/d) + p/d
sp[a_, d_, q_] := a + d*q

(*Equilibrium price and quantity*)
ep[c_, b_, a_, d_] := 
 Quiet[p /. Solve[dq[c, b, p] == sq[a, d, p], p][[1]]]
eq[c_, b_, a_, d_] := 
 Quiet[q /. Solve[dp[c, b, q] == sp[a, d, q], q][[1]]]
(*Equilibrium point and visualization*)
epoint[c_, b_, a_, d_] := Evaluate[{eq[c, b, a, d], ep[c, b, a, d]}]
ehline[c_, b_, a_, d_] := 
 Line[{{0, ep[c, b, a, d]}, epoint[c, b, a, d]}]
evline[c_, b_, a_, d_] := 
 Line[{{eq[c, b, a, d], 0}, epoint[c, b, a, d]}]
ehint[c_, b_, a_, d_] := {0, ep[c, b, a, d]}
evint[c_, b_, a_, d_] := {eq[c, b, a, d], 0}

(*Equilibrium price and quantity with unit tax*)
eput[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Quiet[p /. Solve[c/b - (p + t)/b == sq[a, d, p], p][[1]]]
equt[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Quiet[q /. Solve[c - b*q - t == sp[a, d, q], q][[1]]]
eputc[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := eput[c, b, a, d, t] + t

(*Equilibrium point and visualization*)
epointut[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Evaluate[{equt[c, b, a, d, t], eput[c, b, a, d, t]}]
epointutc[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Evaluate[{equt[c, b, a, d, t], eputc[c, b, a, d, t]}]
ehlineut[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Line[{{0, eput[c, b, a, d, t]}, epointut[c, b, a, d, t]}]
ehlineutc[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Line[{{0, eputc[c, b, a, d, t]}, epointutc[c, b, a, d, t]}]
evlineut[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Line[{{equt[c, b, a, d, t], 0}, epointutc[c, b, a, d, t]}]
qut[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := Evaluate[{equt[c, b, a, d, t], 0}]
pdu[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := Evaluate[{0, eputc[c, b, a, d, t]}]
psu[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := Evaluate[{0, eput[c, b, a, d, t]}]

(*Consumer Surplus - Numerically and graphically*)
cosut[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := (c - eputc[c, b, a, d, t])*
  equt[c, b, a, d, t]/2
cosutarea[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Polygon[{{equt[c, b, a, d, t], eputc[c, b, a, d, t]}, {0, 
    eputc[c, b, a, d, t]}, {0, c}}]

(*Producer Surplus - Numerically and graphically*)
posut[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := (eput[c, b, a, d, t] - a)*
  equt[c, b, a, d, t]/2
posutarea[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Polygon[{{equt[c, b, a, d, t], eput[c, b, a, d, t]}, {0, 
    eput[c, b, a, d, t]}, {0, a}}]

(*Total Surplus - Numerically*)
tosut[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 cosut[c, b, a, d, t] + posut[c, b, a, d, t]

(*Tax Revenue - Numerically and graphically*)
taxur[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := equt[c, b, a, d, t]*t
taxurarea[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Rectangle[{0, eputc[c, b, a, d, t]}, {equt[c, b, a, d, t], 
   eput[c, b, a, d, t]}]

(*Deadweight Loss - Numerically and graphically*)
dwlu[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := (eq[c, b, a, d] - equt[c, b, a, d, t])*
  t/2
dwluarea[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Polygon[{{equt[c, b, a, d, t], 
    eput[c, b, a, d, t]}, {equt[c, b, a, d, t], 
    eputc[c, b, a, d, t]}, {eq[c, b, a, d], ep[c, b, a, d]}}]

(*Define the Tax Revenue function*)
Tu[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := t*equt[c, b, a, d, t]

(*Define the Tax Peak function*)
tustar[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := 
 Quiet[t /. Solve[D[Tu[c, b, a, d, t], t] == 0, t][[1]]]

(*Illustrate tax coordinate*)
tupoint[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] := {t, Tu[c, b, a, d, t]}

(*Visualization*)
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{eqValut}, eqValut = N[equt[c, b, a, d, t]];
  Grid[{{If[eqValut > 0, 
      Column[{Quiet[
         Plot[{dp[c, b, q], sp[a, d, q]}, {q, 0, 1000}, 
          PlotRange -> {0, 2500}, 
          Epilog -> {Directive[LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]], 
            cosutarea[c, b, a, d, t], 
            Directive[LightOrange, Opacity[0.5]], 
            posutarea[c, b, a, d, t], 
            Directive[LightGreen, Opacity[0.5]], 
            taxurarea[c, b, a, d, t], 
            Directive[LightRed, Opacity[0.5]], 
            dwluarea[c, b, a, d, t], Directive[Red, Opacity[1]], 
            PointSize[Large], Point[epointut[c, b, a, d, t]], 
            Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(s\)]\)", 
             epointut[c, b, a, d, t], {-1.5, 0}], 
            Point[epointutc[c, b, a, d, t]], 
            Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(d\)]\)", 
             epointutc[c, b, a, d, t], {-1.5, 0}], 
            Point[qut[c, b, a, d, t]], 
            Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(s\)]\)", 
             qut[c, b, a, d, t], {-2, 0}], Point[pdu[c, b, a, d, t]], 
            Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(d\)]\)", 
             pdu[c, b, a, d, t], {-0.25, -2}], 
            Point[psu[c, b, a, d, t]], 
            Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(s\)]\)", 
             psu[c, b, a, d, t], {-0.25, 2}], Dashed, 
            ehlineut[c, b, a, d, t], ehlineutc[c, b, a, d, t], 
            evlineut[c, b, a, d, t], Directive[LightGray, Opacity[1]],
             PointSize[Large], Point[epoint[c, b, a, d]], Dashed, 
            ehline[c, b, a, d], evline[c, b, a, d], 
            Point[ehint[c, b, a, d]], 
            Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \(*\)]\)", 
             ehint[c, b, a, d], {2, 0}], Point[evint[c, b, a, d]], 
            Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Q\), \(*\)]\)", 
             evint[c, b, a, d], {-0.25, 2}]}, 
          PlotLabel -> "Linear Demand and Supply with Unit-Tax", 
          PlotLabels -> {"Demand", "Supply"}, LabelStyle -> Black, 
          ImageSize -> {400, 250}, Mesh -> {{0}}]], Pane[Style[Column[{
            
            Style["Equilibrium Quantity \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Q\), \
\(t\)]\)=" <> ToString[N[equt[c, b, a, d, t]]], FontColor -> Red], 
            Style["Consumer Price \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \
\(d\)]\)=" <> ToString[N[eput[c, b, a, d, t] + t]], 
             FontColor -> Red],
            
            Style["Consumer Price \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(P\), \
\(s\)]\)=" <> ToString[N[eput[c, b, a, d, t]]], FontColor -> Red], 
            Style["Consumer Surplus CS=" <> 
              ToString[N[cosut[c, b, a, d, t]]], FontColor -> Blue], 
            Style["Producer Surplus PS=" <> 
              ToString[N[posut[c, b, a, d, t]]], 
             FontColor -> Orange],
            
            Style["Tax Revenue T=" <> 
              ToString[N[taxur[c, b, a, d, t]]], FontColor -> Green], 
            Style["Deadweight Loss DWL=" <> 
              ToString[N[dwlu[c, b, a, d, t]]], FontColor -> Red], 
            Style["Total Surplus TS=" <> 
              ToString[N[tosut[c, b, a, d, t]]], FontColor -> Red]}],
          FontSize -> 12, Background -> White], {400, 140}]}],
      Column[{Quiet[
         Plot[{dp[c, b, q], sp[a, d, q]}, {q, 0, 1000}, 
          PlotRange -> {0, 5000}, 
          Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
            Text["No Intersection", {500, 2500}, {-1, 1}]}, 
          AxesLabel -> {"Quantity", "Price"}, 
          PlotLabel -> "Linear Demand and Supply", 
          PlotLabels -> {"Demand", "Supply"}, LabelStyle -> Black, 
          ImageSize -> {400, 250}, Mesh -> {{0}}]], 
        Pane[Style["No Market Equilibrium", FontWeight -> Bold, 
          FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 14], {400, 50}]}]],
     Plot[Tu[c, b, a, d, t], {t, 0, 1500}, PlotRange -> {0, 500000},
      AxesLabel -> {"Unit Tax", "Tax Revenue"}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Unit-Tax and Tax Revenues",
      PlotLabels -> {"Tax Revenue"}, LabelStyle -> Black,
      ImageSize -> {400, 250}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
        Point[tupoint[c, b, a, d, t]], Gray, PointSize[Large], 
        Point[{tustar[c, b, a, d, t], 
          Tu[c, b, a, d, tustar[c, b, a, d, t]]}], 
        Text[Style[ToString[Round[tustar[c, b, a, d, t], 0.01]], 
          Gray], {tustar[c, b, a, d, t], 
          Tu[c, b, a, d, tustar[c, b, a, d, t]]}, {1, -1}], Dashed, 
        Line[{{tustar[c, b, a, d, t], 0}, {tustar[c, b, a, d, t], 
           Tu[c, b, a, d, tustar[c, b, a, d, t]]}}]}]}}]], {{c, 1500, 
   "Choke Price"}, 0, 10000, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 2, "Demand Slope"}, 0.01, 35, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 100, "Reservation Price"}, 0, 10000, 
  1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{d, 2, "Supply Slope"}, 0.01, 35, .1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t, 0, "Unit Tax"}, 0, 1500, .5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["Reset", {c = 1500, b = 2, a = 100, d = 2, t = 0}]]


Update 6/26
I have the right diagram as an individual graph - my trouble was to incorporate "Module[{utaxPeak, upeakValue}, utaxPeak = tustar[c, b, a, d, t];
upeakValue = Tu[c, b, a, d, utaxPeak]" into the code above.
(*Visualization*)
Manipulate[
 Module[{utaxPeak, upeakValue}, utaxPeak = tustar[c, b, a, d, t];
  upeakValue = Tu[c, b, a, d, utaxPeak];
  Plot[Tu[c, b, a, d, t], {t, 0, 1500}, PlotRange -> {0, 500000}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Unit Tax", "Tax Revenue"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Unit-Tax and Tax Revenues", 
   PlotLabels -> {"Tax Revenue"}, LabelStyle -> Black, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 250}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{utaxPeak, upeakValue}], 
     Text[Style[ToString[Round[utaxPeak, 0.01]], Red], {utaxPeak, 
       upeakValue}, {1, -1}], Dashed, 
     Line[{{utaxPeak, 0}, {utaxPeak, upeakValue}}]}]], {{c, 1500, 
   "Choke Price"}, 0, 10000, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 2, "Demand Slope"}, 0.01, 35, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 100, "Reservation Price"}, 0, 10000, 
  1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{d, 2, "Supply Slope"}, 0.01, 35, .1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["Reset", {c = 1500, b = 2, a = 100, d = 2}]]

Thank you!

You write: Plot[Tu[c, b, a, d, t], {t, 0, 1500},..., Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[tupoint[c, b, a, d, t]],..."  Note that "t" in Epilog has not a fixed value, it is a variable.

@DanielHuber I am trying to use the value from the "Unit Tax" slider to have a red coordinate moving along the graph on the right (similar to c, b, a, d) - in contrast to the fixed "700" value

You are using "t" as plot variable and at the same time as variable in Manipulate. Further,  "tutstar" takes the derivative relative to the argument "t". Therefore, you can not give a number for this argument.

@DanielHuber Is there an alternative way? Defining tutstar differently for the comparison or plotting tupoint differently?

I wrote an answer because this is a bit more evolved.

These two changes seem the simplest fix:
tustar[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] =  (* not := *)
 Quiet[t /. Solve[D[Tu[c, b, a, d, t], t] == 0, t][[1]]];

...

Plot[Tu[c, b, a, d, $t], {$t, 0, 1500},...] (* not t *)

Daniel Huber tried to explain why such fixes are needed in their answer and comments. It seems the OP does not appreciate how variables work in the complicated setting of their problem, including the following:

how the variable in Plot[] works: "Plot effectively uses Block" (per docs) and the implications that has while Plot[] is being computed;
how the Front End handles DynamicModule[] variables;
the extra complications Manipulate can add to the way DynamicModule[] variables are handled;
how function arguments are not variables, especially when the argument is used as a variable in D[expr, x].

It's too complicated to explain, especially given how complicated the example is. There are probably better ways to refactor the OP's code than what I called "the simplest fix," but I fear they would take too much time. Also for the OP to understand the changes would take a fair amount of explanation. And as far as understanding and learning, that is better done by modifying the code oneself than by listening to explanations. And it's possible that it's not worth the effort to the OP in this case. Not everything has to be perfect.
One change to the above "simplest fix" does occur to me. The following may prevent a difficult-to-trace bug:
Block[{a, b, c, d, t},
 tustar[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] = 
   Quiet[t /. Solve[D[Tu[c, b, a, d, t], t] == 0, t][[1]]];
 ]

Further reading: Introduction to Manipulate and the related tech notes at the bottom of its page.

Thank you very much!

@Tom You're welcome. Thanks for the accept!

You have 2 problems with the function tustar: The derivative can not be done on a numeric argument but needs a variable. The same is true for Solve.
First the derivative. If you want some derivative of a function evaluated at given arguments you may either introduce a dummy variable, use it for the derivative and then replace it by the actual argument. A more elegant method is to use an abstract derivative. Consider first a simple example:
f[x_]=x^2;
Derivative[1][f]

2 #1 &

This is an abstract function.To evaluate it a e.g. x==3:
f[x_]=x^2;
Derivative[1][f][3]

6

If we have a function of 2 variables and we would like to get the derivative relative to the second argument, you would e.g. write:
f[x_, y_] = x ^2 y^2;
Derivative[0, 1][f]

2 #1^2 #2 &

To evaluate this for given arguments: x0,y0:
f[x_, y_] = x ^2 y^2;
Derivative[0, 1][f][x0,y0]

2 x0^2 y0

Now for the derivative in your function tustar, we would write:
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 0, 1] Tu[c, b, a, d, t]

Now the problem with Solve. You write
tustar[c_, b_, a_, d_, t_] :=  Quiet[t /. Solve[D[Tu[c, b, a, d, t], t] == 0, t][[1]]]

This does not make sense. Tustar returns a value for t, therefore you can not give t as an argument.

Thanks! I don't think the issue is tustar. When you remove '''Red, PointSize[Large], Point[tupoint[c, b, a, d, t]],'' from the second Epilog, then everything works without an error message. It seems that tupoint causes the troubles.

I added a second example for the right diagram. There, I am using values from tustar but I couldn't work this in with the left diagram. I got lots of error messages depending on where I added the second diagram - conflicts with three values in DynamicModule?

I changed tustar[c, b, a, d, t] to tustar[c, b, a, d] as suggested and receive the same error

If I replace Manipulate[] with the changed one, I do not receive any errors. Try with a fresh kernel.
